# postgresql error in postgresql

Tags: xml, postgresql

Can anyone help me? Im trying to execute this query on postgreSQL but I receive this error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "<?"
LINE 1: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        ^

********** Error **********

ERROR: syntax error at or near "<?"
SQL state: 42601
Character: 1
```

This is my sample code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<edmx:Edmx Version="3.0" xmlns:edmx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edmx">
<!-- EF Runtime content -->
```

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<edmx:Edmx Version="3.0" xmlns:edmx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edmx">
EntityType="OBModel.Store.GroupPerjawatan" store:Type="Tables" Schema="public" />
          <EntitySet Name="JuncBgtMengurusSegDtl" EntityType="OBModel.Store.JuncBgtMengurusSegDtl" store:Type="Tables" Schema="public" />
          <EntitySet Name="JuncBgtPerjawatanSegDtl"

Comment: your code should be in your question, not in the comments. [Here's a guide to formatting code.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Answer (score 0):

Your "query" is in fact an `xml` file using the `edmx` schema. This is the format of the Entity Framework ORM by Microsoft and not supported by PostgreSQL. You can execute the `edmx` file against a PostgreSQL database using [npgsql](http://pgfoundry.org/projects/npgsql) or a 3rd party product such as [Openlink Virtuoso](http://docs.openlinksw.com/virtuoso/vdbenginepsql.html).